# JavaFX : How can I set a background image for my stage

Tags: java

I'm writing a code for a bouncing ball program and everything has worked so far but I don't know how to set a background image for my stage. I'm beginner in java (well , obviously) and tried to use ImageView class to set a background for my stage. but no luck so far.

Thank you so much .

```
package particlesystemexample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class ParticleSystemExample extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    ParticleAnimationPane paPane = new ParticleAnimationPane();

    // mouse actions to pause and resume animation
    //paPane.setOnMousePressed(e -> paPane.pause()); // Java 8.0
    paPane.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {  
        public void handle(MouseEvent me) {  
                    paPane.init();            }  
    }); 

    // paPane.setOnMouseReleased(e -> paPane.play()); // Java 8.0
    paPane.setOnMouseReleased(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {  
        public void handle(MouseEvent me) {  
                    paPane.play();            }  
    }); 


    // buttons to increase and decrease animation speed
    paPane.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
        if(e.getCode() == KeyCode.UP){
            paPane.increaseSpeed();
        }
        else if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.DOWN){
            paPane.decreaseSpeed();
        }
    });

    // Create a scene and place it on stage
    Scene scene = new Scene(paPane, 450, 350);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Particle System Example");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
    paPane.init(); // initialize the particles

    paPane.requestFocus();
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

Edit :

I tried using this code to display the image but its not working ...

```
 StackPane sp = new StackPane();
    Image img = new Image("http://mikecann.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/javafx_logo_color_1.jpg");
    ImageView imgView = new ImageView(img);
    sp.getChildren().add(imgView);
```

Comment: Where you do you try use the ImageView class?

Comment: after creating the scene

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I use the BufferedImage and Image classes to deal with all of my image needs.
You can use the Image class for this one.

Here is an example:

```
try {
    Graphics.drawImage(ImageIO.read(new File("Picture.png")), fX, fY, fW, fH, sX, sY, sW, sH,null);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The things starting with F are the bounds for  the rectangle that you will be painting it on.

The things starting with s are the bounds for what part of the picture you are painting.

I'm not exactly sure what the null at the end corresponds to. I just ignore it and everything works out fine.